# How to use Animation Player in Godot like Animated Sprite

Tags: animation, sprites, godot, gdscript

So currently I am using the following code to play my sprites (AnimatedSprite Node).

```
$Sprite.play("Animation Name")
```

However now I want to use the AnimationPlayer Node to play my sprites. How can I do this? I have searched the docs and there is no tutorial and I have searched online but they have to use AnimationTree or a sprite sheet which I don't have. (I have individual sprites).

So my question is how can I use the AnimationPlayer Node in the same way as AnimatedSprite Node.

Note: The reason I am using AnimationPlayer instead of AnimatedSprite because I would like to change collisions during certain frames, but that's for another time.

Disclaimer: To prevent false answers I don't have a sprite sheet. I have individual sprites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer. In Animation Player I just needed to add keys for each frame from my AnimatedSprite Node. Then I would also need to add an animation key to trigger the animation. Hope this helped anyone in the same situation as me. I changed collision by adding keys to change the shape of the collision shape.

Answer (score 2):

The godot docs have a [whole section](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/tutorials/2d/2d_sprite_animation.html#sprite-sheet-with-animationplayer) on just this.

To summarize:

1. Just use a regular `Sprite` instead of `AnimatedSprite`
2. Set the `texture` to your spritesheet
3. Set `hframes`/`vframes` to tell the `Sprite` how to divide up your spritesheet
4. Add keyframes for the `Frame` property of the `Sprite` to the `AnimationPlayer`

Comment: As clearly stated in my question I don’t have a sprite sheet.